# Complexity of std::map::insert_or_assign with hint

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

What is the time complexity of `std::map::insert` or `std::map::assign` with hint provided in the case that the element already exists in the map? CPP-Reference says that it's the same as `emplace_hint`, which says:

> "amortized constant if the new element is inserted just before hint"

But:

1. What if no new element is inserted?
2. And should the hint be `lower_bound` or `upper_bound`?

Comment: Note that using a hint is a win only if you get the hint for free, like inserting essentially sorted data. If you first search for the hint, that is `O(log n)` in itself.

Comment: In this specific use case, I've already done an `upper_bound` search for other reasons beforehand. But I'd like to know whether or not using that value as the hint will give the time guarantee in the case that the element already exists.

Answer (score 0):

If the key already exists, then it is even simpler than that, no need to add new node into the map, just an assignment, so again, ammortized O(1). The words "just before hint" suggest that the hint should be slightly above the key mapped, i.e. an `upper_bound`.

Comment: That's what I would have guessed, but the wording is such that I'm not 100% confident.

Comment: It seems odd that if it already exists, you'd need to provide the iterator to one spot after the existing node, rather than the existing node itself.

Comment: And why's that, exactly? This is for consistency with `insert` and `emplace_hint` that simply do nothing if an element exists already.

Comment: Well, the wording seems quite specific to "if the new element is inserted", so it apparently has nothing to say about a guaranteed complexity if no new element is inserted, which is why I'm wondering if I can rely on it.

Comment: Either you insert the new element before `lower_bound`  or `upper_bound`,  both should  suffice a binary search tree requirement